# Why FreeImage loads image in BGR format?

Tags: c, opengl-es, android-ndk, freeimage

I write game using Android NDK and FreeImage library to load images into my game. It loads images in BGR format. It is possible to load in RGB format? Or I need to swap R and B components manualy?

**Edited**

My device is Samsung Galaxy S4(armv7 archtecture). Here is code`

```
FIMEMORY* fiStream = FreeImage_OpenMemory((BYTE*)data, size);
FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FreeImage_GetFileTypeFromMemory(fiStream);
if (FreeImage_FIFSupportsReading(fif))
{
    dib = FreeImage_LoadFromMemory(fif, fiStream, 0);
}

if (!dib)
    return;

data_ = FreeImage_GetBits(dib);
width_ = FreeImage_GetWidth(dib);
height_ = FreeImage_GetHeight(dib);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width_, height_, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data_ );
```

Comment: How do you decude it's FreeImage that changes your RGB order?

Comment: I use glTexImage2D with type=GL_RGB and the image appears in wrong colors, when I set type=GL_BGR it appears in correct colors

Comment: a couple of questions: 1) does the image display correctly using some other utility to display it?  2) is you computer architecture Big Endian or Little Endian.   strongly suggest posting the relevant code.

Comment: Type? Don't you mean [format](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)?

Comment: @Jongware Ohh I'm sorry, Yes I mean format

Comment: @user3629249 I edited the question. You can see the code.

Answer (score 6):

FreeImage actually doesn't neccessarily use BGR(A) ordering. Section "Pixel access functions" in the [FreeImage documentation](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/freeimage/FreeImage3170.pdf) contains the following statement (emphasis mine):

> **However, the pixel layout used by this model is OS dependant.** Using a byte by byte memory
>   order to label the pixel layout, then FreeImage uses a BGR[A] pixel layout under a Little
>   Endian processor (Windows, Linux) and uses a RGB[A] pixel layout under a Big Endian processor (Mac OS X or any Big Endian Linux / Unix). This choice was made to ease the use
>   of FreeImage with graphics API.
>
> This subtle difference is however transparent to the user. In order to make pixel access OS
>   independent, FreeImage defines a set of macros used to set or get individual color
>   components in a 24- or 32-bit DIB.

However, these macros will not help you when you want to use FreeImage's raw pixel data as source for OpenGL.

But I don't know what your issue with this is. OpenGL will accept BGR(A) as well as RGB(A) as image data. And actually, FreeImage's choice is not bad, as BGR(A) is most likely the native data format on such platforms, so that using this format represents the most efficient way to transfer image data.

Comment: I use freeimage in android application which uses Opengl ES, as I know Opengl ES doesn't support BGR(A) order.

Comment: Oh, it indeed doesn't. There might be some options: a) drop freeimage altogether. b) reorder the channels on the CPU manually c) just swizzle the channels when applying the textures in the shaders.

Comment: I don't like these options but I don't have any other. Anyway thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

FreeImage can be built to always load in RGB order independent of the architecture. Use #define FREEIMAGE_COLORORDER=FREEIMAGE_COLORORDER_RGB. If you're using Android.mk to build FreeImage, add the following line to it:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DFREEIMAGE_COLORORDER=FREEIMAGE_COLORORDER_RGB
```

Documentation for this can be found in Source/FreeImage.h if you search for FREEIMAGE_COLORORDER:

> Color-Order:
>
> The specified order of color components red, green and blue affects
>   24- and 32-bit images of type FIT_BITMAP as well as the colors that
>   are part of a color palette. All other images always use RGB order. By
>   default, color order is coupled to endianness:
>
> little-endian -> BGR
>
> big-endian    -> RGB
>
> However, you can always define FREEIMAGE_COLORORDER to any of the
>   known orders FREEIMAGE_COLORORDER_BGR (0) and FREEIMAGE_COLORORDER_RGB
>   (1) to specify your preferred color order.